# ¿Cómo filtrar por id (run) y sumar a dos columnas de otra tabla a través de un trigger en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy haciendo un disparador el cual, cada vez que inserte un empleado, le sume uno a la columna 'empleados' y  30000 a la columna 'bono_responsabilidad' de la tabla supervisor.

Este es el código de la tabla empleado

```
    CREATE TABLE empleado
(
  run_empleado    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  nom_empleado    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  dir_empleado    VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  fono_empleado   BIGINT NOT NULL,
  sueldo_base   INT NOT NULL,
  comision       DECIMAL(4,2),
  id_categoria    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  run_supervisor  VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT PK_runempleado PRIMARY KEY (run_empleado)
);
```

Este es el código de la tabla supervisor

```
select run_supervisor, count(*) empleados, count(*) * 30000 bono_responsabilidad
into supervisor from empleado
where run_supervisor IS NOT NULL
group by run_supervisor;
```

Esto es lo que tengo del trigger, pero afecta a todas las columnas de la tabla supervisor, cuando debería filtrar, seleccionar un run_supervisor, y solo sumarle a ese en específico. De antemano, gracias

```
create trigger dis_empleados_insertar
on empleado
for insert
as
begin
   declare @bono int
   set @bono = 30000
   update supervisor set empleados = empleados + 1 from supervisor
   update supervisor set bono_responsabilidad = bono_responsabilidad + @bono
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro porque no has relacionado los registros que vienen en la inserción con la tabla `supervisor`.

```
create trigger dis_empleados_insertar
on empleado
for insert
as
begin
   declare @bono int;
   set @bono = 30000;
   update supervisor 
        Set empleados = Isnull(empleados,0) + 1
            , bono_responsabilidad = Isnull(bono_responsabilidad,0) + @bono
   from supervisor
        inner join inserted on supervisor.run_supervisor = empleado.run_supervisor;
   
end
```

Fíjate que realizamos el join contra `inserted`, que se corresponde con los registros que se están insertando. Por otro lado, para que hacer dos updates si son las mismas columnas de la misma tabla.

Luego hay que protegerse, de cuando se inserta el primer empleado o el primer registro de supervisor que no tenga bono_responsabilidad, ya que null + 30000 tiene como resultado null.

[image: Res]

Además siempre tienes que tener en cuenta, que los triggers no son para una fila, son de conjuntos, y una sentencia de inserción puede hacerlo para varios empleados a la vez, de diferentes o iguales bono_responsabilidad.

[Trigger After insert](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/)

Comment: Funcionó de maravillas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda